# SSH: Switch from public key authentication to password authentication

Tags: ssh

I have an account i SSH into.  How do i switch to using a plain old password to login rather than my public/private key pair?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This is a terrible idea. I don't approve.

Comment: Is the next step re-enabling Telnet? (WHY do you want to do this?)

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are asking how to 1) Enable password authentication on a server where it is disabled or 2) Tell your ssh client to try password authentication before trying public key authentication? Shane's answer is appropriate if you're trying for #1, mine is for #2.

Comment: One general problem with a private key is that you have no idea how it is being handled by clients. They could be carrying the private key around unencrypted on a USB memory for all I know. Passwords are good because they can be forced to adhere to a policy on a creation time.

Comment: I want to do this because I have removed the key because I have to go back to a server I had abandoned, and password recovery goes faster if my keys don't take up so many attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PasswordAuthentication` option in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file controls whether passwords are allowed.

Really, though.  **Use public keys**.

Comment: The question is about disabling public key on client side not server side.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to do this temporarily, you could connect to the server with `ssh -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' server`. If you want to do this permanently, on the server you could remove your public key from *~/.ssh/authorized_keys* or on your computer you could add the following to *~/.ssh/config*

> Hostname server
>   PubkeyAuthentication no

Answer (score 0):

if you know the password it should be a matter of supplying the password... if you dont know it and have access to the system, simply reset it by running

```
passwd
```

to force it to use password login, you will have to remove your private key file from its currently location (linux/mac) or disable it in your ssh client

you also need to check that password auth is enabled in your ssh config

however i also echo the other comments, switching from key auth to password is NOT recommended as you are effectively lowering your level of security, i would be asking why you are making this kind of switch

Comment: This is not a good answer to the question

Comment: I agree. I have a user with a dual boot, windows or linux. The keys were set up on linux butnot windows. This has meant no git access for the machine when in windows